# Access to changes in ODataModel

Tags: sapui5

I am using sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel and at a certain point of time in my app I would like to look into what changes have been made (to be more precise, how many entityset entries have been created). It's quite easy to do when accessing the mChangedEntities property of the model. However this is not "allowed" by the project guidelines. Has somebody an idea how to tackle this issue? I don't quite understand why there is a hasPendingChanges() function, but not a getPendingChanges() function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the source code. The ODataModel, implementing OData Version 2.0, has a method **getPendingChanges**, at least in UI5 version 1.34.8. As it has no JSDoc comments it is not shown in the documentation.